# Calling a function from a child directive & using a variable in the parent directive

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 directives:

Directive `A` which has a `$scope.originalData` variable that gets data from an http request, and also has a function to use that variable:

```
    $scope.findStepEducatByActId = function(act_id){
        console.info('findfindStepEducatByActId',$scope.originalData);
        if(angular.isDefined($scope.originalData.connections)){
            angular.forEach($scope.originalData.connections[0].con_detail,function(value,key){
                if(value.act_id_from == act_id){
                    return value.educategory_from;
                }
                if(value.act_id_to == act_id){
                    return value.educategory_to;
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

Directive `B` (which is called `flowChart`) has this function passed to it in the HTML file template of `A`

```
<flow-chart findStepEducatByActId="findStepEducatByActId(act_id)"></flow-chart>
```

And I also am printing out `$scope.originalData` in that file: `{{originalData}}`

Directive `B` is simply calling that function:

```
angular.module('slmFlowClass').directive('flowChart', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'scripts/modules/slmFlowClass/FlowClass.FlowChart.Template.html',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            findStepEducatByActId: '&'
        },
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $scope.showNodeTooltip = function($event, node){
              $scope.findStepEducatByActId('708663');
            }
    }
```

When I run this, I get a log: `findfindStepEducatByActId undefined`, but in HTML `$scope.originalData` I can see the data this variable contains.
So my question is, why when I call this function from `B` the `$scope.originalData` is null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use angular directive's 'require' property.
In your directive B,

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'scripts/modules/slmFlowClass/FlowClass.FlowChart.Template.html',
    replace: true,
    require: 'A'
    ....
```

For more info about this, please refer angular documentation for directive. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive